# Exlude row with same key from 1st select if exists in 2nd select statement in UNION

Tags: t-sql

I have two tables Part and Service Entry Part.  The first statement returns all parts and the second statement returns parts with a service type of 13.

What I need to do is if the second select returns a part then the record from second select should be inlcuded and that part from the first select should be be excluded

```
 DECLARE @run_log TABLE(      
        [Instrument] nvarchar(max),       
        [SubSystem] NVARCHAR(max),      
        [AbPartNumber] NVARCHAR(max),       
        [RSLMSPartID] int,      
        [PartDescriptionWithParent] NVARCHAR(max),
        [PartRevisionNumber] NVARCHAR(max),
        [ServiceEntryID] int,
        [Date] datetime,
        [TSBNumber] nvarchar (max),
        [CRNumber] nvarchar(max) 
        )  
insert  @run_log 
-- parts with default revision number
select 
     System.SystemFullName as Instrument,
     Part.System as SubSystem,
     Part.AbPartNo as AbPartNumber,
     Part.ID as RSLMSPartID,
     Part.PartDescriptionWithParent,
     Part.RevisionNumber as PartRevisionNumber,
     NULL as ServiceEntryID,
     NULL as Date,
     NULL as TSBNumber,
     NULL as CRNumber
from Part
     inner join InstrumentType on Part.InstrumentTypeID = InstrumentType.ID
     inner join SystemModule on SystemModule.InstrumentTypeID = Part.InstrumentTypeID
     inner join System on System.ID = SystemModule.SystemID
     WHERE ((@PlatformID =0) OR (System.PlatformID = @PlatformID) OR (@PlatformID = 12 AND System.PlatformID <= 2)) 
     AND (@SelectedSystemID is null OR System.ID IN(select  * from dbo.SplitInts_RBAR_1(@SelectedSystemID, ',')))
     AND (@SelectedAbIDs is null OR Part.ID IN (select * from dbo.SplitInts_RBAR_1(@SelectedAbIDs,','))) 
     AND (@SelectedSubSystems is null OR Part.System IN (select * from dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(@SelectedSubSystems,',')))
     AND System.Active = 1 and Part.Active = 1 
     ORDER BY SubSystem,RSLMSPartID
 ;WITH RunLogs AS(       
        SELECT  *    
        FROM    @run_log r

 )
 select * from RunLogs
UNION   
 select System.SystemFullName as Instrument,
         Part.System as Subsystem, 
          Part.AbbottPartNo as AbPartNumber,
         Part.ID as RSLMSPartID,
         Part.PartDescriptionWithParent,
         ServiceEntryPart.PartRevisionNumber AS PartRevisionNumber,
         ServiceEntryPart.ServiceEntryID,
         ServiceEntry.ServiceDateTime as Date,
         ServiceEntry.TSBNumber,
         ServiceEntry.CRNumber
 from Part
         inner join ServiceEntryPart on ServiceEntryPart.PartID = Part.ID
         inner join ServiceEntry on ServiceEntry.ID = ServiceEntryPart.ServiceEntryID
         inner join systemmodule on ServiceEntryPart.SystemModuleID = SystemModule.ID
         inner join System on System.ID = SystemModule.SystemID
         cross apply
         dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(ServiceEntryPart.ServiceTypeIDs, N',') M2
         JOIN  dbo.SplitStrings_Moden('13', N',') P ON (M2.Item = P.Item)
         WHERE System.Active = 1 AND Part.Active = 1 
         AND (@SelectedSystemID is null OR System.ID IN(select  * from dbo.SplitInts_RBAR_1(@SelectedSystemID, ',')))
         AND ((@PlatformID =0) OR (System.PlatformID = @PlatformID) OR (@PlatformID = 12 AND System.PlatformID <= 2)) 
         AND (ServiceEntry.ServiceDateTime between @StartDate and @EndDate)
         AND (@SelectedAbIDs is null OR Part.ID in (select * from dbo.SplitInts_RBAR_1(@SelectedAbIDs,',')))   
         AND (@SelectedSubSystems is null OR Part.System IN (select * from dbo.SplitStrings_Moden(@SelectedSubSystems,',')))
```

Comment: dont' use a union either use a left join on the key where the value in the 2nd table is null, or use the MINUS operator instead of the union, but only if all fields are the same in both queries.

Comment: if i use minus or left join, i get the record from the first table. My logic is if it exists in second table then use the record from second table and exclude it from the first select

Comment: ah sorry, then left join is the way to go, and use coalesce on each of the fields pulling from second table first, then first table like `coalesce(B.SystemFullName, RunLogs.SystemFullName) as Instrument`

Comment: i cant left join because few of the fields which I want to display  does not exist in the first table and coalesce on a null column which does not exist in first table will return error and I  have to cross apply in the second table.

Comment: Even if you materialize the second query as a second CTE first then do the joins?  The cross apply should have no bearing on the results if both queries have been materialized as a CTE first.